# How to get more debug info for C++ std::ofstream writing to device?

Tags: c++, file, std, iostream, ofstream

Good day, I am trying to debug this C++ code which interacts with XDMA device:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream output_;
    const char* output_name = "/dev/xdma/card0/h2c0";

    output_.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    output_.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0);
    output_.open(output_name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    std::streamoff offset = 0x1e00000;
    output_.seekp(offset, std::ios::beg);

    const char buf[1] = "";
    std::streamsize size = 1;
    auto pos = output_.tellp();

    output_.write(buf, size); // <--- IOSTREAM ERROR

    output_.seekp(pos + size, std::ios::beg);
    return 0;
}
```

But this program fails on `output_.write(buf, size);` - with quite a vague error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear: iostream error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And, if I wrap this `output_.write(buf, size);` in a try & catch block:

```
    try {
        output_.write(buf, size);
    }
    catch (std::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.code().message() << "(" << e.code().value() << ")\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

it changes to `iostream error(1)`. This doesn't tell a failure reason... I know for sure that I can write to 0x1e00000 offset, because the alternative C code is working flawlessly. So the error is in C++ code or library. **How to get more debug info?**

Comment: soooo, why not `std:cerr << e.what()`? and `std:cerr << e.code();`

Comment: @KamilCuk these variants also don't tell anything useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't succeed in getting more debug info, the solution was to downgrade the XDMA driver, which provides `/dev/xdma/card0/h2c0` device, from `v2017.1.47` to the older `v2017.0.45` version (which needed a custom patch to work on new OS). Unfortunately these new drivers are really buggy...